# Can I return a single item from a JSON array in POST method API?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

As I do POST method, it returns the whole array as a response. Is it possible to return for example only the ID after successful request?

I have

```
{   "requestid": 1
    "requestname": "Sample request",
    "projectmanager": "Josh",
    "creationdate": "2022-09-26T23:48:00Z"  }
```

What if I only want to return the result as

```
{ "requestid": 1 }
```

Here's my view for reference:

```
class CreateRequestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
serializer_class = RequestSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `create` is perfect for the job. Firstfully get what a generic response returns, then modify the view's response as you please.

```
class CreateRequestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({"requestid": response.data['requestid']})
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this! I have an issue tho! Why could it be returning null? :/ The data is saved in the DB but the response is null.

Comment: No idea. Try to `print(response)` and see if all data is ok.

Comment: Where can I see the result of print?

Comment: In your server's console :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `JsonResponse`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def your_view():
    ...
    your_id = 1
    return JsonResponse({'requestid':your_id})
```

Comment: Question is about DRF, not pure Django.

Comment: The OP didn't mention that when I gave this answer

Comment: Yes, it was mentioned. Look at tags.